# How do I do string search in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to do string search in Elasticsearch like:

```
This is the content stored in elasticsearch
```

and I want it to match with "`content stored in`" for example, but not with "`in stored content`". Currently with the simple search both match.

Also I want to match with partial strings like "`ontent stor`" (not full words).

I know there are things like wildcard search, but they will scan all documents. I'd like to use features to have it run faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcard search are heavy. You can use [ngram token filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenfilter.html) in your analyzer and do term search. It will take care of matching partial string. Make sure that you use a different analyzer for search(without ngram token filter) if you are not using term search.

Comment: will term search actually match a string without tokenizing it?

Comment: If you use the ngram token filter for your index it will generate ngram tokens. For eg: "a simple text" will result in tokens a, "a ", a s, a si', .... si, sim, simp, simpl, ..... and so on. You can refer the doc for more detail. Now when you do a term search it will return the doc if it matches any of the term. In term query your input string does not get analyzed.